# How to install an old version of Python on Mac - macOS Sierra (10.12)

Tags: python, macos, py2exe

I am trying to run some scripts I wrote several years ago in Python 2.4.4
At the time I was using Windows XP, probably. I had also created executables (using py2exe) for different versions of the tool which I created for my company's customers.
Today I use Macs. My iMac has 2 versions of Python (2.7.12 and 3.5.1) and I am running macOS Sierra (10.12).

When trying to run my tool I came to a stumbling block not being able to import compiled code (.pyc files) which were part of the old compilation.

Hence I thought I'd install Python 2.4.4, which was the exact Python revision used in 2007 on my Windows machine.
When I try to install Python 2.4.4 on Mac, using the [Universal installer](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.4.4/python-2.4.4-macosx2006-10-18.dmg), I am told, via an error message at the end of the installation process, there is nothing to install.

In Windows it was possible to install as many versions of Python in different folders, **how to do the same on a Mac?**

THANKS

Comment: Installing the old version of Python won't help you. pyc files are specific not only to the version, but also to the architecture; it's very unlikely that ones created on Windows XP will run on Macs.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I had just learned Python at the time and had not figured ways that could make the tool run on any machine in the future. I am now installing 2.4.4 on Windows10, hoping there will not be any architectural issues between Windows10 and WindowsXP....